# How to put an if statement in another one in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I am trying to put an if statement inside another like this :

```
void initState() {
        super.initState();
        FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser().then((res) {
          if (res != null) {
            if (userType.text == 'Student') {
              Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/StudentsPage');
            } else if (userType.text == 'Teacher') {
              Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/TeacherPage');
            } else if (userType.text == 'Admin') {
              Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/AdminPage');
            }
          } else {
            LoginScreen();
          }
        });
      }
```

But It gives me this error that there is a text that was called on null, so if anyone has an idea.

I'm using `FireBase` database.. and I am retrieving the data using this:

```dart
    void getUserData() async { 
try { 
firestoreInstance .collection('Users') .document(usernameController.text) .get() .then((value) {
 setState(() { 
email = (value.data)['email'];
 password = (value.data)['password']; 
gender = (value.data)['gender']; 
username = (value.data)['username']; 
userType = (value.data)['userType'];
 }); }); 
print('$userType'); 
}
 catch (e) { 
    print(e.toString);
 } }
```

[image]

Comment: I think `userType.text` is `null` here

Comment: It's more likely that `userType` is `null`, which is why it's saying it was _called_ on `null`.

Comment: the userType is stored in the database and It is not null

Comment: How can you be absolutely sure if it is not being checked?

Comment: userType: 'Student'

Comment: What data type is `userType`? Is `text` a valid getter?

Comment: Okay..do one thing..to make sure that it(`userType`) is not null..try printing it before the first if statement..just a suggestion..!

Comment: Ok I checked and It is null but how It says in the database it = 'String'

Comment: What database are you using? Please share more code that allows us to see the source of `userType`.

Comment: Post the code in the question, not the comments.

Comment: Dou you call getUserData anywhere? I don't see it. If not userType will be null.

Comment: yes with a button down

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `userType` is a `String` object and therefore has no `text` getter method. Remove the `.text` and it seems that your code would work fine.

```
if (res != null) {
  if (userType == 'Student') {
    Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/StudentsPage');
  } else if (userType == 'Teacher') {
    Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/TeacherPage');
  } else if (userType == 'Admin') {
    Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/AdminPage');
  }
}
```

Comment: It is still null

Comment: You need to share more code in your question. What's currently provided isn't giving a full enough scope.

Comment: I can't put all the code in it I will do a screenshot ok ?

Comment: That's discouraged. Create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).